# Calculating WGS84 (EPSG:4326) area in C# or SQLGeometry?

Tags: coordinate-system, c#, area

I am not normally a GIS developer, I am just helping out with a bug and I am stumped on what is going on here, could I get some help please.

I have two calculations, one in 4326 (WGS84) and one in 3857 (Google Mercator).  The coordinates were converted from 4326 -> 3857 and I have confirmed those are correct with ArcGIS and various online site conversion tools.  The results I have are...

```
-114.50,38.0=-12746081.696,4579425.813

-114.00,40.0=-12690421.950,4865942.280
```

If I do an estimate of the area for 3857 by calculating the difference in the x and y points then multiplying the differences and dividing by 1 mil to get sq km, I get the result just under 16,000 sq km.  Running SqlGeometry.STArea on a polygon bbox using these points this gives me a similar number.

If I convert the lat long to UTM I receive the numbers ...

```
-114.50,38.0=719510.335753775,4208764.46330096

-114.00,40.0=243900.352021924,4432069.05663229

Excel Calculations
Easting         Northing        sq m                    sq km
719,510.3358    4,208,764.4633      
243,900.3520    4,432,069.0566  
--------------------------------------------------------------------
475,609.9837    223,304.5933    106,205,894,001.5610    106,205.8940
```

Sites used to convert to UTM

http://www.latlong.net/lat-long-utm.html

http://www.rcn.montana.edu/Resources/Converter.aspx

http://www.earthpoint.us/Convert.aspx

Running the same calculation of the difference and the area gives me the result of 106,205 sq km.

The code currently calculates the lat long by doing the following on a polygon of the bbox ...

```
SqlGeography geog = SqlGeography.STGeomFromWKB(aoi.STAsBinary(), (int)aoi.STSrid);
area = (double)geog.STArea();
```

This gives me about 9,600 sq km.

**What I need to know...**

I am trying to find out which calculation is correct.  I am leaning toward 3857 being correct as I the calculations give me approximatly the same numbers no matter how I do them.  Since I feel that 4326 is incorrect, I would need a better way to calculate this in the current application (uses C# and SQLGeometry).  If someone sees an error in my calculations please let me know and how to do this better if so.

Comment: Neither. You can't scale areas from degrees to hectares (square miles etc..). If you want an area in metres (or feet) project to a suitable projected coordinate system and calculate the area there. WGS84 UTM has zones that cover the whole world; you can determine from the coordinates whether it's north or south of equator and which zone it's in.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson If I understand you correctly, if I receive a request in 4326 and I want to know the area.  I need to convert it to, say 3587 (or another meter projection system), and perform the area calculation there.

Comment: Yes, but probably not one so distorted. 3587 is good because it covers the whole world (like WGS84) but flattening out a sphere is going to lead to severe distortion away from the centre point. A projection like UTM still distorts but it does so from a central meridian at intervals of 6 degrees so suffers much less distortion from being flattened.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson When I did the manual conversion from the lat long of 4326 to UTM, you can see results above, I have a completely different number.  I used http://www.latlong.net/ to make the conversion, other sites gave me similar numbers.  Am I seeing over 100,000 sq km, I am updating my question to show the excel spreadsheet numbers.

Comment: 106K looks right based on those numbers. From two points you can calculate the area by (MaxX - MinX) * (MaxY - MinY).. What I could suggest is look at the area in QGIS or similar in UTM and see of those numbers look roughly correct. In C# you should be able to use Proj.4 lib to do your projections without relying on an external site. Google Web Mercator is quite distorted so It wouldn't surprise me to see that kind of difference.

Comment: I am certain that the correct area for the coordinates is 16K.  The reason that I am certain of this is because of the 3857 calculations, and based on estimates using maps.google.com that the north south distance is about 286 km and the east west distance is 55 km.  The multiplation of 286 km and 55 km is 15730 sq km.  This is also very close to the number returned from SQLGeometry on 3857.  I am suggesting that converting to UTM did not give me the correct area.

Comment: You may also have a problem that the polygon doesn't have enough vertices to adequately reflect its shape in a projected coordinate reference system (ProjCRS). That is, if the longitude line might be curved in the ProjCRS, then two points aren't enough.

Comment: The 106km2 value is wrong because your UTM coordinates are wrong. Whatever you're using is treating each coordinate separately. The two longitude values are in different zones which is why the 'left' value has a X value of 700k while the right one is 200k. The true separation in X is more like 44km. Also it's not a rectangle in UTM so a quick rectangular calc will have errors too.

Comment: EPSG::3857 does NOT maintain areas so the 16km2 calculation is wrong. If you instead project it into UTM (still not equal area but designed for the data's location) or an equal area projection, the areas are 9621 km2 versus 9615 km2 for an undensified  polygon.

Comment: Good point @mkennedy, a projected envelope is a trapezoid. It's safest to set the zone based on the centroid of the original envelope (or at least one point) so that they all end up in the same zone - another reason why I would use Proj.4 to do the projection - to ensure all points end up in the same zone. Equal area would be much better as you say but as not-a-GIS it might be too hard to instruct how to make your own using a Proj string, but it would be the most accurate.

Comment: I am converting the two points to a bounding box, sorry if I was not clear in the question about that.  I have confirmed that the polygon bounding box hits all four corners and completes the shape at the starting point.  The same process is used to create the polygon for each process.  @mkennedy How do you convert lat long to UTM, you mentioned that I have incorrect numbers?  In the mean time I will research Proj4Lib.

Comment: Other sites that are giving me the same Easting and Northing UTM numbers.  http://www.rcn.montana.edu/Resources/Converter.aspx and http://www.earthpoint.us/Convert.aspx

Comment: OP, please go back to Earthpoint and MSU and look at the UTM zone that's attached to the calculated coordinates. The 700k X (LL of the bounding box) is calculated in zone 11. The 200k X (UR) is calculated in zone 12. You cannot use these to calculate the area. The eastern edge of zone 11/western edge of zone 12 is -114.

Comment: @mkennedy The UTM zones are something that I did not know about, thank you for letting me know.  Is it possible to split by zone, do the area calculations for each zone and add the areas?  Based on my research it sounds like there are 60 zones and each are 6 degrees apart.  Or I can use the formula using degrees from the International Date Line (180Deg) to calculate the zone Round(latitude/6) to determine the zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the fact that the EPSG:3857 projection does not preserve areas, the units of it are not real meters. Only at the equator they match real meters, while they get stretched the more to the poles you go.

UTM does not preserve areas either, but it minimizes distance errors as long as you are within the same UTM zone (which is not the case in the example). So it uses real meters as units.

The only correct way to calculate areas is using an equal area projection. For Northern America, you can try ESRI:102008

```
+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs
```

---

Using QGIS and the built-in `$area` function of the field calculator, I get for your 0.5x2.0 degree area:

```
EPSG:2163  8105.49 km² (based on a sphere)
EPSG:3857 15947.43 km² (google square meters)
EPSG:32107 9617.65 km² (NAD83 Nevada East)
EPSG:32611 9622.15 km² (WGS 84 / UTM zone 11N)
ESRI:12008 9616.38 km² (North_America_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic)
```

As you see, EPSG:3857 is worth for nothing. It is just a popular visualization, nothing more.

Comment: With the understanding that the meters are stretched, I still see results that are too widely different from what they should be.  I would expect a small % difference with the stretching.  I am seeing with the SQLGeometry results about 60% reduction in the area 15.9K sq km vs 9.6K sq km.  That seems more like an error in the SQLGeometry results (could be user input).  With my manual calculations I see 15.9K vs 106K sq km.  That is almost certainly an incorrect calculation somewhere.

Comment: The UTM calculation across two zones (11N and 12N) is obviously wrong. If you shift your area half a degree to the East or West, you will be within one UTM zone and get reasonable values. For the others, see my extended answer.

Comment: Mercator projection maintains angles and shapes not distances nor areas. The linear distortion is 1.269  at 39N.

Comment: The updated numbers are very helpful to see.  From what I understand from your updates, the 15K km² is incorrect and the 9.6K km² is correct.  In that case I should be converting the 3857 to something else to calc area.  Does that sound correct?

Comment: You can take the original EPSG:4326 degree values and transform them to something useful.